# Kubernetes: how to set cpuManagerPolicyOptions align-by-socket

Tags: kubernetes

How do we set the `cpuManagerPolicyOptions` for `align-by-socket`?

Currently this is what I have implemented on the node that I would like this to take effect on:

`/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`:

```yaml
systemReserved:
  cpu: "1"
  memory: "2Gi"
kubeReserved:
  cpu: "1"
  memory: "2Gi"
cpuManagerPolicy: "static"
cpuManagerPolicyOptions:
  align-by-socket: "true"
featureGates:
  CPUManager: true
  CPUManagerPolicyOptions: true
  CPUManagerPolicyAlphaOptions: true
  CPUManagerPolicyBetaOptions: true
```

From the documentation [static-policy-options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#static-policy-options), it states that I need to enable `CPUManagerPolicyAlphaOptions` which I did as seen in the config above.

After that I ran:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/cpu_manager_state
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl stop kubelet
sudo systemctl start kubelet
```

But I noticed my pods are still not aligning based on the socket (I have 2 CPU sockets). Is there anything that I am missing?

EDIT: I tried with `full-pcpus-only` and same results as before.

Comment: what is your `CPU` configuration in the pod spec?  Basically `.spec.containers.resources.requests.cpu` ?
how did you verify that your pods are not aligned based on the socket?? And also which version of Kubernetes you are dealing with?

Comment: Also `align-by-socket` is alpha feature, and is hidden in most of the cases. You can use `full-pcpus-only`